# Access and edit property of parent class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have a simple `Parent` class object like this:

```
class Parent {
  children: Child[] = [];

  addChild() {
    this.children.push(new Child());
  }
}
```

As you can see above, I can add children classes to it which look like this:

```
class Child {
  removeSelf() {
    //Remove this class instance from the Parent class 
       which holds it in it's "children" array
  }
}
```

I was wondering if it there is a way to remove an instance of a Child class from the Parent class's "children" array, and doing so on the Child class instance itself (like in the example code, calling `removeSelf()`)?

I know it would be possible to remove a Child class by calling another function on the Parent class, something like this for example:

```
class Parent {
  children: Child[] = [];

  addChild() {
    this.children.push(new Child());
  }
  //Call this -->
  removeChild(index: number) {
    this.children.splice(index);
  }
}
```

However, it would be nicer the other way. Any advice on how to deal with situations like this would be appreciated !

Note: Keep in mind I am new to programming and JavaScript. I am just exploring my options :)

Comment: Like by passing the parent instance to the child class and then using it to remove the child

Comment: Thanks @esQmo_. Would it be possible for you to add some example code to your answer?

Comment: Sure: ```class Parent {
  children: Child[] = [];

  addChild() {
    let child = new Child(this);
    this.children.push(child);
  }

  removeChild(child: Child) {
    let index = this.children.indexOf(child);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.children.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}

class Child {
  parent: Parent;

  constructor(parent: Parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  removeSelf() {
    this.parent.removeChild(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: When a new Child is created, it is passed a reference to the Parent that created it. This reference is stored in the parent property of the Child class. The removeSelf method on the Child class can then use this reference to call the removeChild method on the Parent, passing itself as an argument. The Parent then removes this child from its children array. This way, a child can remove itself from its parent’s children array. Hope this is what you want?

Comment: This is a nicer way of doing it, thanks.